# SelendroidDriver cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, selendroid

I am trying to test a Selendroid test on Eclipse and followed the necessary steps on how to run it. Unfortunately, the two libraries that are mentioned above cannot be resolved to a type. I have added all the necessary jar files in the build path however, but it still cannot be resolved. Is there another way to resolve this problem? Images as here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shall share the imports (in text) and lib structure attached to the question itself and not link,

Comment: already edited.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this error and finally came to know that the paths have been changed in the latest releases. 
Use these paths and it shall work:

```
import io.selendroid.common.SelendroidCapabilities;

import io.selendroid.client.SelendroidDriver;
```

Tested this for versions 0.15.0 and 0.17.0